# Excel UDF #VALUE! Error

Tags: excel, user-defined-functions, valueerror

The below Code Counts the number of unique names is a specific column after inputting the data into an array. It works perfectly when running in the the immediate window. But when using as a UDF it throws #Value Error. I am taking all the data into an array and checking the array and getting a number out of it and returning it. I am not modifying any excel sheets or changing the worksheet's environment. Please help!!1

```
Public Function Operator_Count(Aircraft As String) As Integer

Dim Aircraft_Name As String
Dim Data_Array() As Variant
Dim Row_Count As Integer
Dim Col_Count As Integer
Dim Col_Alph As String
Dim Row_Counter As Integer
Dim Master_Series_Column As Integer
Dim Status_Column As Integer
Dim Operator_Column As Integer
Dim InnerLoop_Counter As Integer
Dim Operator_Array() As Variant
Dim Operator_Array_Transpose() As Variant
Dim Array_Counter As Integer
Aircraft_Name = Aircraft
Operator_Count = 0

'ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Aircraft Data").Activate

Row_Count = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Aircraft Data").Range("A2", Range("A2").End(xlDown)).Rows.Count
Col_Count = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Aircraft Data").Cells(1, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
Col_Alph = ColumnLetter(Col_Count)

Data_Array = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Aircraft Data").Range("A1:" & Col_Alph & Row_Count + 1).Value2

For Row_Counter = 1 To Col_Count

    If Data_Array(1, Row_Counter) = "Master Series" Then

    Master_Series_Column = Row_Counter

    End If

Next

For Row_Counter = 1 To Col_Count

    If Data_Array(1, Row_Counter) = "Status" Then

    Status_Column = Row_Counter

    End If

Next



For Row_Counter = 1 To Col_Count

    If Data_Array(1, Row_Counter) = "Operator" Then

    Operator_Column = Row_Counter

    End If

Next


'Resizing the data array
ReDim Operator_Array(0, 0)
'Adding column to the data array
InnerLoop_Counter = 0
For Row_Counter = 1 To UBound(Data_Array)

    If Data_Array(Row_Counter, Master_Series_Column) = Aircraft_Name And (Data_Array(Row_Counter, Status_Column) = "In Service" Or Data_Array(Row_Counter, Status_Column) = "On order") Then

        Flag = 0
                    For Array_Counter = 0 To UBound(Operator_Array, 2)

                        If Operator_Array(0, Array_Counter) = Data_Array(Row_Counter, Operator_Column) Then
                            Flag = 1
                            Array_Counter = UBound(Operator_Array, 2)
                        End If
                     Next

                     If Flag <> 1 Then
                         ReDim Preserve Operator_Array(0, InnerLoop_Counter)
                         Operator_Array(0, InnerLoop_Counter) = Data_Array(Row_Counter, Operator_Column)
                         InnerLoop_Counter = InnerLoop_Counter + 1
                     End If

     End If

Next

Operator_Count = UBound(Operator_Array, 2)


End Function


Function ColumnLetter(ColumnNumber As Integer) As String
    Dim n As Integer
    Dim c As Byte
    Dim s As String

    n = ColumnNumber
    Do
        c = ((n - 1) Mod 26)
        s = Chr(c + 65) & s
        n = (n - c) \ 26
    Loop While n > 0
    ColumnLetter = s
End Function
```

Comment: Run your `UDF` as a `SUB` first.  You will then be able to trap the offending line of code.

Comment: `ColumnLetter` looks like it's making it more complex than needed - that's the first function I've seen that appears to work on all column numbers though.  But, you could replace the function with:  `With ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Aircraft Data"): Data_Array = .Range(.Cells(1, 1), .Cells(Row_Count + 1, Col_Count)).Value: End With` (use `Cells` to reference row & column numbers).

Comment: Thanks for the replies. @Gary's Student: The code is running good when I run in the Immediate Window. it is giving me the right answer.
@ Darren Bartrup-Cook: I can make the column letter Static and will try

Comment: It worked - just removed the 
Row_Count = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Aircraft Data").Range("A2", Range("A2").End(xlDown)).Rows.Count
and replaced with
With ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Aircraft Data")

    Row_Count = .Range("A2", .Range("A" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp)).Rows.Count

End With

With ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Aircraft Data")

    Col_Count = .Cells(1, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column

End With